# Save Simulink Scope Data to figure through matlab code

Tags: matlab, scope, matlab-figure, simulink

As a student I am currently working on a Matlab Simulink project. I am quite new to using Matlab/Simulink (few weeks).

I am using a load cell from which I gather data through UART and display it on a Matlab Simulink Scope. This works all fine. My next step was to implement and run a Matlab “.m” file with which I can open Simulink and start the simulation. The aim is to do a 24h Test cut into 1h “pieces” and to save the scope data to a figure each hour. So my Simulink simulation runs for 1h, stops and starts again, and so on. Through Matlab and a “for” loop I do the measures 24 times.

What I didn’t figure out:

Save the Simulink Scope Data to a figure through Matlab code, each time one increment in the loop ist done. I can get the figure from my Simulink Block but that’s not what I wanted (by that I mean that I literally get a screenshot from the Simulink Block; just to be clear).

`for i=0:1:24

[…]

% Print to JEPG

fig = get_param('Simulink_Project','handle');
saveas(fig,sprintf('Figure%02d.jpeg',i ));

[…]

end`

I hope that what I stated, was clear. 
Thanks for your help.

Regards

hohmchri

Comment: Rather than trying to print the Simulink Scope directly, you are probably better off saving the data to the workspace (via the saving options of the scope), then using `simplot` to plot the data into a standard MATLAB figure, and then printing/saving the MATLAB figure.

Comment: @PhilGoddard thanks for the quick answer. I figured then, that i could get the data (measured values) through a `To Workspace` block in Simulink and `xlswrite` in Matlab.

Comment: assuming you still have the `Scope` block in the model, there is no need for an additional `To Workspace` block.  Just use the save data to work space option in the scope.